# Call a method or function from Objective-c in AppleScript

Tags: applescript-objc

I'm trying to use [LestMove](https://github.com/potionfactory/LetsMove) to be more precise
the second implementation method where it says:

Option 2:

Copy the following files into your project:

PFMoveApplication.h
PFMoveApplication.m
If your project has ARC enabled, you'll want to disable ARC on the above files. You can do so by adding -fno-objc-arc compiler flag to your PFMoveApplication.m source file. See [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project/6658549#6658549)

If your application is localized, also copy the 'MoveApplication.string' files into your project.

Link your application against Security.framework.

**In your app delegate's "-[applicationWillFinishLaunching:]" method, call the PFMoveToApplicationsFolderIfNecessary function at the very top.**

but I'm not able to call the method / Class, could someone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as AppleScript handlers need to be in a script object, I think Objective-C methods need to be in a class in order for everything to get linked up.  That thing is a bit of a mess for use with ASObjC, are you asking how to _use_ an Objective-C class in general, or how to _fix_ this one in particular?

Comment: hi red_menace, How to fix this in particular, but it would be nice if you could explain how to do that in general too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are a couple of ways to set up an Objective-C class in your AppleScriptObjC project:

- Add the file(s) to the project - the Objective-C class name will be
  the one used in the `@interface`/`@implementation` declarations
- Add an outlet property in the AppleScript class/script you are using, e.g. `property someProperty : missing value`

  1. Instantiate the class programmatically:

     `set someProperty to current application's ClassName's alloc's init()`

  or

  2. Connect stuff up with the Interface Builder:

     - Add an **NSObject** (blue cube) from the library to your project
     - Set the class of the object/cube to the class name of the Objective-C file(s) in the **Identity Inspector**
     - Connect the AppDelegate IB Outlet to the object/cube in the **Connections Inspector**
- After setting up the outlet property, the Objective-C methods can be used like any other script/class:

  `someProperty's handler()`

---

That [LetsMove](https://github.com/potionfactory/LetsMove) project wasn't really set up for AppleScriptObjC, but I was able to tweak it a bit to get it running.  I'm not that great at *writing* Objective-C, but the following worked for me using a new default AppleScript project with Xcode 10 in Mojave (the original file is over 500 lines long, so I'm just highlighting the changes):

1. Add `PFMoveApplication.h` and `PFMoveApplication.m` files to the project (the class name is `LetsMove`)
2. Add `Security.framework` to **Link Binary With Libraries** in **Build Phases**
3. As described in the original project README, add the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` to the Objective-C file in **Compile Sources** of the **Build Phases**

--  Now to alter the Objective-C files a bit:

4. Move the `@interface` declaration to the `.h` file and include the redefined method signatures below in it:
5. The `PFMoveToApplicationsFolderIfNecessary` and `PFMoveIsInProgress` methods are redefined as instance methods:

   ```
   - (void)PFMoveToApplicationsFolderIfNecessary;
   - (BOOL)PFMoveIsInProgress;
   ```
6. Redefine the above method signatures in the `.m` file, and include those methods in the `@implementation` section - to do this, move the `@end` to just before the helper methods (after the `PFMoveIsInProgress` method)
7. Remove the `isMainThread` statement at the beginning of the `PFMoveToApplicationsFolderIfNecessary` method - this is not not needed (AppleScript normally runs on the main thread), and fixes another issue
8. There is still a little stuff in there from the original app such as NSUserDefaults, so for your own project, give it a look to see if anything else needs changing (dialog text, etc)

And finally, in the `AppDelegate.applescipt` file, the following was added to `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`

```
    current application's LetsMove's alloc's init()'s PFMoveToApplicationsFolderIfNecessary()
```

Comment: I tried to implement using only ApplescriptOBJC and it works but I can't relaunch the Application, it just won't open after copying to the Applications folder and closing. code here:https://pastebin.com/MdK6wyQT

Comment: Are you not using that Objective-C class?  If you are now doing your own version, note that **LetsMove** uses an **NSTask** to perform the quit/relaunch, since once the application quits it obviously won't be running in order to do anything else.

Comment: I tried to replace the ```shell script "mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of myApp & space & "/ Applications"```

with this: from the ```shell script "cp -R " & quoted form of POSIX path of myApp & space & "/ Applications"``` but not working copy only Binary file.

Comment: To shut down the app, move it, and start it up from the new location, you will need to launch a separate task, since the app isn't going to continue with anything once it quits - take a look at what the **LetsMove** Objective-C class is doing (it is in the `Relaunch` method near the end).

Comment: this: ```NSString *script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(while /bin/kill -0 %d >&/dev/null; do /bin/sleep 0.1; done; %@; /usr/bin/open %@) &", pid, preOpenCmd, quotedDestinationPath];``` ?

Comment: That kills the specified PID, pauses a bit, then opens the new path.  NSTask is independent, and continues until it finishes or is terminated, so your application would need to do something similar.

Comment: Could you instruct me how to implement your answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381785/applescript-app-not-responding-force-close in the code example I posted on pastebin? If you wish I open a new post with this question.

Comment: Probably be better to ask a new question with the details of what you have done.

Comment: done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333493/how-to-relaunch-the-moved-application-to-a-new-location